# how to transfer ETH in starknet contract cairo 1.0?

Tags: ethereum, starknet, cairo-lang

My Starknet contract uses cairo v2, but ETH tokens in starknet are deployed with cairo v0. But Cairo v0 and Cairo v2 are two very different versions in syntax and data types. So how to transfer ETH in cairo starknet contract v2

I tried using IERC20 to use ETH token but without success
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyBvJ.png

Comment: Have a look at: "Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

You we need to use `IERC20Camel` to interact with camel cased contract (which many of ERC20 contracts are).

```rust
#[starknet::interface]
trait IERC20Camel<TState> {
    fn totalSupply(self: @TState) -> u256;
    fn balanceOf(self: @TState, account: ContractAddress) -> u256;
    fn allowance(self: @TState, owner: ContractAddress, spender: ContractAddress) -> u256;
    fn transfer(ref self: TState, recipient: ContractAddress, amount: u256) -> bool;
    fn transferFrom(
        ref self: TState, sender: ContractAddress, recipient: ContractAddress, amount: u256
    ) -> bool;
    fn approve(ref self: TState, spender: ContractAddress, amount: u256) -> bool;
}
```

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/cairo-contracts/blob/main/src/token/erc20/interface.cairo#L34C3-L34C3

##### Steps are like this,

1. Create a dispatcher,

```rust
let erc20_dispatcher = IERC20Dispatcher { contract_address };
```

2. `transferFrom` after you have approval

```rust
erc20_dispatcher.transferFrom(sender, recipient, amount);
```

##### Approval to move tokens with `approve`

Before you can call `transferFrom` (or `transfer_from`) your contract needs to have approval for the tokens you want to transfer.
This is usually done as a multi-call. So when you ask the client to sign the transaction that eventually calls `transferFrom` you add in a call to `approve` right before it within the same transaction.